# Error sending an email with function InsertDE (Ampscript)

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions, url, insert

This is my first contribution to this community. I'm having problems with sending an email when i'm using the function InsertDE  whereas using other functions such as UpsertDE works fine, and the email is received perfectly.

The problem comes when im using InsertDE ampscript code. The email is being sent sucessfully from SFMC, but never arrive to my inbox (Outlook, Gmail, or other accounts). Anyone know what it´s happening?
Here is the example with InsertDE:

`%%[
Var @url, @update, @pdf, @lookuprows, @update2
Set @lookuprows = LookupRows("Prueba_Coupons_feb17",  "Email", emailaddr) 
SET @row2 = Row(@lookuprows,1)
Set @date = Field(@row2, "Fecha de canjeo")
Set @update2 = 
**InsertDE("Coupons_feb17", @fecha, NOW())** 
Set @update = IIF(EMPTY(@date), @update2, "Error") 
Set @pdf =   RedirectTo('http://example.pdf')
Set @url = Concat(@pdf,@update)
]%%`

As you can see, I would like to introduce data (Now Date in this case) when a subscriber click on the URL to get a coupon.

Thanks in advance,

Hughs!

Comment: What's the primary key on your `Coupons_feb17` Data Extension?

Comment: Hi Adam. There isn't  any field with primary Key in my DE. Could be that the reason why it's not working the send test? I cannot mark as a primary key any field now in the DE. I would try to create a new DE, and try to use it in order to check if that is the problem...